# python flask: unable to work with method parameters

Tags: python, mysql, flask

i have the app.py file which gets the form data through request.form() and i pass those values to a database method get_data() as parameters but i keep getting the following error "UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'data' where it is not associated with a value".
I have checked both functions independently and they are working fine.

'''
app.py:

```
@app.route("/result", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_result():
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.form.get("firstName")
        lname = request.form.get("lastName")
        nhs_number = request.form.get("nhs_number")
        get_data(fname,lname,nhs_number)      
    return render_template("result.html")
```

db.py:

```
def get_data(fname,lname,nhs_number):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        first_name = fname
        last_name = lname
        nhs_number = nhs_number
        result_patient = conn.execute(text(f"select first_name,last_name,nhs_number from patient where nhs_number = '{nhs_number}' "))
    for x in result_patient.all():
        search_str = json.dumps(dict(x._mapping))
        data = json.loads(search_str)
    if data["first_name"] == first_name and data["last_name"] == last_name:
        data = data
    else:
        data = "no information found"
    return data
```

'''

Comment: It is probably because your code does not enter the for loop, because "result_patient" is empty. Remove the single quotations and the spaces before and after "=" from your database query.